# SharePoint 2013 Transparent Background Image

Tags: development, site-template, sitepages

I am trying to insert a background image I have saved in my "Images" files in SP 2013.

I have not done this in a very long time. I entered the following code snippet, but I'm pretty sure I need to insert it somewhere else. Maybe from SP Designer?

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-mainarea{
    background-image:url('image.png');
}
.s4-ca
{
    background-color:transparent;
}
</style>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "transparent image" ? 
images are not "transparent" they can have an A axis for translucid but that's how you create them in your PNG. 
if the png has no transparency then it won't be transparent no matter what you do

Answer (score 0):

now.

talking about the image and the location you want to add it.. i remember that the s4-mainarea belongs to the header. do you want to add your image to the header ? you need to find the right selector of where you want to place it.

for this you should better use google chrome, right click on the location where you want to find it and click "inspect" over there you'll see the html code where you need to find the specific control you want to use (the main window will shade the location you are selecting), once you find the html control you want to edit you have to right click it > copy > copy selector

then you'll have something like this :

that's the selector you'll need to add in your script editor :

```
    <style>
    #s4-workspace{
              background-image:url('http://sitename/subsite/library/image.png');
         }
    </style>
```

Comment: I wanted to add the background image to the entire page.

Comment: then you need the "#s4-workspace", that's the WHOLE site (excluding the tenant header)

Answer (score 0):

The demo is testing in publishing feature enabled site collection.

Create a CSS as below:

```
 #s4-workspace{ 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#s4-workspace::after{
content: "";
    background-image:url('/SiteAssets/panda.jpg');
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Upload the CSS and image to SiteAssets library.

Insert below link in seattle.html(backup before you updating).

[image]

(Ignore image size)
[image]